# Best Practice : How to get a unique identifier for the object

Tags: c++

I've got several objects and need to generate a unique identifier for them which will not be changed/repeated during the lifetime of each object.

Basically I want to get/generate a unique id for my objects, smth like this

```
int id = reinterpret_cast<int>(&obj);
```

or

```
int id = (int)&obj;
```

I understand the codes above are bad ideas, as int might not be large enough to store the address etc.

So whats the best practice to get a unique identifier from the object, which will be a portable solution ?

Comment: You can use `size_t` which should be as large as pointer types, for example. Or if you just need to check for same/different why not store the pointer itself?

Comment: If your id's don't need to persist across program runs or address space bondaries, the address will do the job. `uintptr_t` is the large-enough integer type.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on your "uniqueness"-requirements, there are several options:

- If unique within one address space ("within one program execution") is OK **and your objects stay where they are in memory** then pointers are fine. There are pitfalls however: If your objects live in containers, every reallocation may change your objects' identity and if you allow copying of your objects, then objects returned from some function may have been created at the same address.
- If you need a more global uniqueness, for instance because you are dealing with communicating programs or data that is persistent, use GUIDs/UUIds, such as [boost.uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/uuid/).
- You could create unique integers from some static counter, but beware of the pitfalls:

  - Make sure your increments are atomic
  - Protect against copying or create your custom copy constructors, assignment statements.

Personally, my choice has been UUIDs whenever I can afford them, because they provide me some ease of mind, not having to think about all the pitfalls.

Comment: If one thinks in terms of "variables" and "values", then the first bullet effectively says this: If you need a unique identifiers for variables, so no two variables have the same ID, you can use their addresses; if you need to have unique identifiers for values, so no two variables contain values with the same IDs, using variables' addresses won't work.

Answer (score 12):

If the objects need to be uniquely identified, you can generate the unique id in the constructor:

```
struct Obj
{ 
   int _id;
   Obj() { static int id = 0; _id = id++; }
};
```

You'll have to decide how you want to handle copies/assignments (same id - the above will work / different id's - you'll need a copy constructor and probably a `static` class member instead of the `static` local variable).

Comment: This needs to be synchronized if the app is multi-threaded, use something like InterlockedIncrement for Windows for example

Comment: And if int is 32-bits and you intend this process to run indefinitely, you should be prepared to handle negative ids (or make it unsigned) and handle wrapping around back to zero (thus you must check for id uniqueness in your set of objects when creating a new object/id).  Oh, and for good measure, I would make zero an invalid handle.

Answer (score 5):

When I looked into this issue, I fairly quickly ended up at the **Boost UUID**  library (universally unique identifier, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/uuid/). However, as my project grew, I switched over to **Qt's GUID** library (globally unique identifier, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quuid.html).

A lesson learned for me though was to start declaring your own UUID class and hide the implementation so that you can switch to whatever you find suitable later on.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is a class then you could have a static member variable which you intestinal to 0. Then in the constructor you store this value into the class instance and increment the static variable:

class

```
Indexed
{
public:
   Indexed() :
       m_myIndex( m_nextIndex++ )
   { }

   int getIndex() const
   { return m_myIndex; }

private:
   const int m_myIndex;
   static int m_nextIndex;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a bad idea to use the object address as the unique (for this run) identifier, directly. Why to cast it into integer? Just compare pointers with `==`:

```
MyObject *obj1, *obj2;
...
if (obj1 == obj2) ...
```

This will not work, of course, if you need to write IDs to database or the like. Same values for pointers are possible between runs. Also, do not overload comparison operator (`==`).

Comment: `obj1 == obj2` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't see how this yields undefined behaviour. Could you please elaborate (and supply a reference to the Holy Standard)?

Comment: This is just a code fragment, not a finished program. I added now '...' to make clear some more lines of code are expected there.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Well, sure, but.. I at least assumed that he meant to have a `// Do more stuff here ...` between the declaration and the check.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore And it led to him updating his post, so I guess it's a good thing. :) Though in the future it may be even more helpful if you'd added the explanation of what exactly was wrong to begin with. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique id for distributed environment use [boost::uuid](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/uuid/)